# Make Moq Setup recognize an array with values

Tags: c#, moq

How do I make Moq `Setup` recognise two arrays with the same values as equal?

I have this method that takes a list of strings as parameter.

```
class Hospital{
    Patient[] GetPatients( DateTime[] dates ){
       ...
    }
}
```

I setup a mock where I require the exact parameter.

```
var hospital= new Mock<Hospital>( MockBehavior.Strict );
hospital.Setup( m => m.GetPatients( new [] { new DateTime(2016,10,30) } ) );
```

Then, in my testee, I do the call.

```
hospital.GetPatients( new [] { date } ); // date is DateTime(2016,10,30).
```

It does not recognise my mock.
This is natural as `Equals` does not consider two arrays equal.
But how do I make it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe at the time you asked this question Moq did not have this implemented. But now it should work the way you wrote.

Moq does not use simple .Equal() method to verify if value are the same. It has a bit more complicated matching created. If it find IEnumerable then it uses .SequenceEqual()

Since Array is Ienumerable it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to (realise it is possible to) put a lambda in `It.Is` like `It.Is<>( => )`

```
var hospital= new Mock<Hospital>( MockBehavior.Strict );
hospital.Setup( m => m.GetPatients(
    It.Is<DateTime[]>( d => AreEqual(d) ) );
```

and a helper method

```
bool AreEqual( DateTime[] dates ){
    return dates.Count == 1
        && dates[0] == new DateTime( 2016, 10, 30 );
}
```